# Redux toolkit createAction with generic type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to use Redux toolkit `createAction` to generate an action that take a generic type. Types are as follows.

```
export interface ObjectArray {
    externalId: string
}

export interface CarFilters {
  arrayType: string[];
  objectType: ObjectArray[];
}

export type FilterOptionValue = string | number;

export type FilterMapValue = FilterOptionValue[] | string;

export interface ShipFilters {
  [key: number]: FilterMapValue;
}

type AppliedFiltersType = {
    cars: CarFilters;
    ships: ShipFilters;
}

type PathValue<T extends object, K extends keyof T = keyof T> = T[K] extends unknown ? T[K] : never;

export type AssingValueType<
  Category extends keyof AppliedFiltersType = keyof AppliedFiltersType, 
  Key extends keyof PathValue<AppliedFiltersType, Category> = keyof PathValue<AppliedFiltersType, Category>
> = {
  category: Category,
  filterKey: Key
  value: PathValue<AppliedFiltersType[Category], Key>;
}
```

Reducer and actions

```
import { createAction, createReducer } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

import { AssingValueType, AppState } from "./types";

export const updateAppliedFilterValue = createAction<AssingValueType>(
  "UPDATE_APPLIED_FILTER_VALUE"
);

const initialState = {
  appliedFilters: {
    cars: {
      arrayType: [],
      objectType: []
    },
    ships: {}
  }
} as AppState;

const reducerCreator = createReducer(initialState, (builder) => {
  builder.addCase(updateAppliedFilterValue, (state, action) => {
    state.appliedFilters[action.payload.category] = action.payload.value;
  });
});

export default reducerCreator;
```

Intention is to make the action parameters strict type checked so it cannot be called with inconsistent types.

Eg

updateAppliedFilterValue({
category: 'car',
filterKey: 1,
value: 3
})

should be identified as a error from ts compiler.

Pure function like follows works

```
const updateFilterValues = <Category extends keyof AppliedFiltersType, Key extends keyof PathValue<AppliedFiltersType, Category>>(params: AssingValueType<Category, Key>) => {

  return params;
}
```

But I'm not clear on how to create generate action with `createAction`
I have trouble creating action inferring the generic types.

[Codesandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/lingering-tdd-tpvbk?file=/src/store/filters.ts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the issue you are having is strictly related to the definition of AssigningValueType.

Solution:

```
export type AssingValueType = {
  [Category in keyof AppliedFiltersType]:
    { category: Category } & {
      [Key in keyof AppliedFiltersType[Category]]: {
        filterKey: Key,
        value: PathValue<AppliedFiltersType[Category], Key>
      }
    }[keyof AppliedFiltersType[Category]]
}[keyof AppliedFiltersType]
```

Explainer
`AssingValueType` is a [Discriminated Union Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions) with `Category` a keyof AppliedFiltersType aka `'ships' | 'cars'`.

For each potential Category we also define `filterKey` in a similar fashion. `value` can be defined relative to Category and Key.

`&` [type intersection operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) is used to merge the { filterKey, value } with { category }.

The last and most important step is the
`{[Category in keyof AppliedFiltersType]: ...}[keyof AppliedFiltersType]`
which extracts a union type for each of the keys of AppliedFiltersType.

In short...
`{ships: {category: 'ships', ...}, cars: {category: 'cars', ...}}` becomes `{category: 'cars' ...} | {category: 'ships'}`

Regarding your initial concern, `createAction` should work like a charm the way you intended to use it.

Comment: Indeed it works like a char.m. That is dump copy/paste. Still I need to understand it. Thanks anyway.